# What is is best way to take screenshot and convert it into gray scale image using pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
image = ImageGrab.grab().convert('L')
```

I did it but it's too slow on my computer.

Comment: That seems to be the canonical way to take a screenshot and convert it to grayscale solely using Pillow. What does _it's too slow on my computer_ actually mean? Do you take screenshots inside a loop, and the number of screenshots per second is too low? What's the context of your question? I can't imagine taking a single screenshot following the presented way will take thaaat long...

Comment: Which version of PIL?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the [mss](https://pypi.org/project/mss/) module is very fast at taking screenshots. It unfortunately can't convert the image to grayscale. You'd have to use something like [opencv2](https://opencv.org/) for this. (Don't worry, opencv is written in C++ and *very* fast)